# Hive. Check stripe size for existing ORC storage

Tags: hadoop, hive, orc

I have two scripts which parse data from raw logs and write it into ORC tables in HIVE. One script creates more columns and another less. Both tables partitioned by `date` field.

As the result I have ORC tables with different sizes of files.
Table with larger number of columns consists of many small files (~4MB per file inside each partition) and tables with less columns consists of few large files (~250 MB per file inside each partition).

I suppose it happens because of stripe.size setting in ORC. But I don't know how to check size of stripe for existing table. Commands like "show create" and "describe" don't reveal any custom settings, it means that  stripe size for tables should be equal to 256 MB.

I'm looking for any advice to check stripe.size for existing ORC table.
Or explanation how file size inside ORC tables depends on data in that tables.

P.s.It matters later when I'm reading from that tables with Map Reduce and there are small number of reducers for tables with big files.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Hive ORC File Dump Utility:  [ORC File Dump Utility](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+ORC#LanguageManualORC-ORCFileDumpUtility).

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I did some dumps, but I can't figure out anything useful from output. For example, I see that small files have just 2 stripes meanwhile large files have 62 stripes. It gives me no idea about way to solve my issue :)